# Number sum medley

Tags: code-golf, number, fibonacci

**Winner**

[CJam, 74 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38421/31300) by Optimizer

**Task**

- Take an input of an integer `n` through the console or a file.
- Find the sum of the `n`th prime, square, triangular number, and cube. Add to that the factorial of the first decimal place of the square root of `n` and the `x`th Fibonacci number, where `x` is the first digit of the square of `n`.
- Print that sum to the console or to a file.

**Rules**

- Entries must complete the task above for all positive integers less than 100.
- Standard loopholes are of course not allowed.
- Any built-in function that finds primes or tests for primes in any way is not allowed.
- This is code golf.

**Summary of numbers to sum**

```
nth prime (where 2 is the first)
square of n
nth triangular number (where 1 is the first)
cube of n
factorial of the first decimal place of the square root of n
xth Fibonacci number, where x is the first digit of the square of n (2 is the third Fibonacci number)
```

**Examples**

Note: The numbers being summed are included here just for clarity.

```
Input: 1
Output: 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 7

Input: 11
Output: 31 + 121 + 66 + 1331 + 6 + 1 = 1556

Input: 99
Output: 523 + 9801 + 4950 + 970299 + 362880 + 34 = 1348487
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CJam, <s>83 76 75</s> 74 bytes

This can be golfed more. Will update when I golf it further.

```
T1{_2$+}A*]ri:NN*s1<i={X):Xmf,1=T+:TN<}gXNN*_N*N_)*2/Nmqs_'.#)=~,:)1+:*]:+
```

The online compiler for CJam does not return proper Double numbers(required by mq, root). So try it in the Java version as mentioned on [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/) page

Answer (score 3):

### Java, 323

```
class C {public static void main(String[]s){int n=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt(),p=2,j,k=1,t=0,a=1,b=0,c;z:for(;t<n;p++){for(j=1;++j<p;)if(p%j<1)continue z;t++;}j=(int)Math.round(Math.sqrt(n)%1*10);for(t=0;t++<j;k*=t);for(c=j=n*n;(j/=10)>9;);for(t=0;++t<j;a+=b,b=a-b);System.out.print(p-1+c+(c+n)/2+c*n+k+a);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt(),                                                                    p = 2,
            j,
            k = 1,
            t,
            a = 1,
            b = 0,
            c;

        // prime
        z:
        for (t = 0; t < n; p++) {
            for (j = 1; ++j < p; ) {
                if (p % j < 1) {
                    continue z;
                }
            }
            t++;
        }

        // factorial
        j = (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(n) % 1 * 10);
        for (t = 0; t++ < j; k *= t);

        // fibonacci
        for (c = j = n * n; (j /= 10) > 9;);
        for (t = 0; ++t < j; ) {
             a += b, b = a - b);
        }

        System.out.print(p - 1 + c + (c + n) / 2 + c * n + k + a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `a += b, b = a - b` should not have a `)` before the semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, <s>152</s> <s>136</s> <s>133</s> 132 bytes

```
For[n=Input[i=m=0],m<n,If[Divisors@++i=={1,i},m++]];#&@@Fibonacci@IntegerDigits[n^2]+i+3n^2/2+n/2+n^3+Floor[-10(Floor[s=Sqrt@n]-s)]!
```

I'm first determining the *n*th prime number in a loop (also avoiding `NextPrime` - it's not explicitly disallowed but I think it's not intended to be allowed either), and then I'm simply summing all the required numbers in a single expression. There is one simplification: I'm combining *n<sup>2</sup>* and the triangular number *n(n+1)/2* into *3n<sup>2</sup>/2* and *n/2*.

Input is taking via prompt, which is the closest thing to STDIN you get in Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 159 bytes

```javascript
n=>{
f=a=b=1
for(N=n**.5*10%10|0;N;)
f*=N--
for(N=(n*n+"")[0];--N;)
b=a+(a=b)
f+=a+n*(n*n+n+-~n/2)
for(i=2;n;n-=j<=i++)
for(j=1;++j<i;)
j=i%j?j:i
return f+i-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzLbsIwFET3/ooICcn2lSGXEh410@5Y5geqLgIkyBa6rgJ008evpy7tpupuNOfMxOa1Oe/78HJxkg7tsMUgeHhTHRrswKpLva4h1k4qy@WYy/fS196ozqJ27hdrsUKjkXkqn71z33iHhnR@yCLlKPamCLlPmc7MbRYw8@LFIW4QiH7KCPZEcRPyR0QYx8d4H1TfXq69FB0Fxx/DPsk5ndrJKR31Vq/XBuC7@Wq@Whr1lzGbAii4qhb/UF4tzfAF)